# receiving asn.1 message via java socket

Tags: java, asn.1

I am using BinaryNotes to encode and decode my ASN.1 messages and I have classes that were compiled using the bnotes compiler. I am using the encoding/decoding example contained in the pdf here:

http://bnotes.sourceforge.net/BinaryNotes.pdf page 11

here is the example code:

```
// Encoding for Java
TestSequence sequence = new TestSequence();
sequence.setField1(10L);
sequence.setField3("Hello");
// Inner class for implicitly ASN.1 type declaration
TestSequence.Field4ChoiceType choice = sequence.new Field4ChoiceType();
choice.selectField2(0.5);
sequence.setField4(choice);
IEncoder< TestSequence> encoder=CoderFactory.getInstance).newEncoder("BER");
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
encoder.encode(sequence, outputStream);`
```

Now I have an input stream that contains my encoded data but in order to decode I need to know the class of the sequence which in the example case is "TestSequence".

```
// Decoding for Java
IDecoder decoder = CoderFactory.getInstance().newDecoder("BER");
// Decoding the specified input stream
TestSequence seq = decoder.decode(stream, TestSequence.class);
System.out.println(seq.getField1());
if(seq.isField3Present())
System.out.println(seq.getField3());
```

If I receive the data as a ByteArrayInputStream how do I determine which classname to pass to the decoder.decode method?

Comment: You have to know the data type you receive and therefore you have to know the class name.

Comment: What is the appropriate method to communicate that if you are implementing asn.1? I was anticipating there would be some type of tag encoded with the message.

Comment: If you want tag encoded messages you have to use ASN.1 messages in DER encoding. For BER encoded messages you have to know everything, what message comes next and what structure the message has, for DER encoded messages the structure is contained within the data. Of course BER encoded messages are much smaller than DER encoded messages...

Comment: @Robert, I think you are confusing PER with BER in this case. PER is bit packed and schema informed; BER is a proper superset of DER (in fact any DER-encoded message can be decoded by a BER decoder). I'm not familiar with BinaryNotes, but StormLord is correct that tags could be helpful in identifying the type of message.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I was able to change from ber to der and I didn't find that the class names were included. When looking in the spec under section 8 it shows the identifier octets and I was anticipating this would be specific to "TestSequence" but instead I get 0x30 for the first octet of the bytearray which is just plain sequence.    http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf

Comment: @StormLord - without seeing the specification you're using, it's hard to say exactly why. But since TestSequence is, in fact, a SEQUENCE, it stands to reason it should be tagged as such unless the specification declares otherwise. ([Here's an intro to tagging in ASN.1](http://r.duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fpowerasn.ncottin.net%2Fdownload%2FASN1_Tagging.pdf) for some introduction; PDF link.)